# Can a Logic App use the "When an item is created" trigger on a View?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have a consumer of my application that wishes to interact with some of the data in my database using Azure Logic Apps.

- In order to use the "When an item is modified" trigger, the row needs a `timestamp` column.
- In order to use the "When an item is created" trigger, the row needs an `IDENTITY` column.

To avoid polluting my schema with unrelated columns, I created a new schema with a table and a view in it, the table contains the required columns and the view joins that table with the actual data table in the main schema, the idea being that the Logic App will consume this view.

Unfortunately however, the view is only "available" to the modified trigger of the Logic App, *not* the created trigger. Is this supposed to work, or is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Logic App use the "When an item is created" trigger on a View?

I tried it by creating trigger on the view based on the table where original table has identity column.

Definition of view and parent table:
[image]

Logic app triggers configuration:
[image]

It triggered the successfully.
[image]

**From above its we can conclude that "When an item is created" trigger working on a View.**

Comment: Interesting, I wonder whether the limitation is to do with the join inside the view, or perhaps having multiple schemas.